# Ethernaut Challenge Magicnumber

Tags: solidity, opcode

This my OPCODE:

```
 INIT: 
       PUSH 0x0a(10 OPCODES=10 bytes) = 600a
       PUSH 0x0c = 600c
       PUSH 0x00 = 6000
       CODECOPY - Where, current location of runtime code, size of runtime code = 39
       PUSH 0x0a = 600a
       PUSH 0x00  = 6000
       RETURN (position=0x00, value size=0x0a) = f3
         Result = 600a600c600039600a6000f3

 RUNTIME: 
       PUSH 0xfa = 60fa
       PUSH 0x80 = 6080
       MSTORE 0x80,0xfa = 53
       PUSH 0x20 = 6020
       PUSH 0x80 = 6080
       RETURN (0x80, 0x20) = f3
         Result = 60fa60805360206080f3
```

Contract deployment passes successfully, but when I submit the challenge it says I haven't solved it yet. Could somebody tell me where is the error in my OPCODE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your bytecode is wrong since your contract returns

```
113078212145816597093331040047546785012958969400039613319782796882727665664000
```

when called.

To check, I deployed a contract

```
contract DeployBytecode {
    
    // Create contract from bytecode
    function deployBytecode(bytes memory bytecode) public returns (address) {
        address retval;
        assembly{
            mstore(0x0, bytecode)
            retval := create(0,0xa0, calldatasize)
        }
        return retval;
   }
}
```

and deployed your bytecode with it, then got the address back and use this

```
contract Answer {
    function whatIsTheMeaningOfLife() external view returns(uint){
    }
}
```

to call the whatIsTheMeaningOfLife() and get that huge number.

Hope this helps